# Trying to install blender getting stuck on creating shortcuts

Tags: windows, installation

I'm trying to install Blender at my school but when it's getting close to finishing it gets stuck on "Creating Shortcuts"

Comment: Downloading and installing are two different processes.

Comment: Try using the zip version. There is no need to install it: just download, unzip and run the app from the newly created folder.

Comment: Me too, Blender 3.0, Windows 10. 2022.